# Google App Engine. How to customize the login page?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

in my app i use default Login Page the code is:

```
public class GiuseppeIT_defaultServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

    String thisURL = req.getRequestURI();

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    if (req.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        resp.getWriter().println("<p>Hello, " +
                                 req.getUserPrincipal().getName() +
                                 "!  You can <a href=\"" +
                                 userService.createLogoutURL(thisURL) +
                                 "\">sign out</a>.</p>");
    } else {
        resp.getWriter().println("<p>Please <a href=\"" +
                                 userService.createLoginURL(thisURL) +
                                 "\">sign in</a>.</p>");
    }
  }
}
```

When i invoke this request i view Login Page Default :
[image: Screenshot Login Default]

But how i can customize this page for change for example colour, character and others?
There is an example?

THANKS to all and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize that page, it's something that comes from Google (actually the screenshot you provided comes from GAE Devserver and once deployed - it will look differently, but also - not customizable).

If you really need to have that page your own way - you need to implement your own authentication rather than using what Google provides.